# Одежда и надежда

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Являются ли слова *одежда* и *надежда* однокоренными?

Comment: В современном языке эти слова не являются однокоренными. Что касается исторического родства, то, может быть,  этот вопрос  можно выяснить с помощью этимологического словаря (Шанского, например). Кстати, Вы можете сами ответить на свой вопрос, если нет других ответов.

Answer (score 4):

С точки зрения школьного подхода, который признает однокоренными только слова, сохранившее некоторую общность значений, - нет. Значения слишком сильно разошлись. Скажем, "проверочным"словом одно для другого быть не может.

С академическими же представлениями всё несколько сложнее. Академическая грамматика признает два подхода: статический (синхронический) и динамический (диахронический).

С точки зрения первого из них язык рассматривается в текущем состоянии, "как есть". Поэтому эти слова не считаются однокоренными (но, возможно, родственными).

Диахронисты же рассматривают язык в его исторической изменчивости, они видят, что ***надежда*** и ***одежда*** восходят к одному очень древнему морфу (deti), от которого произошло еще много всяких русских слов, в том числе и глагол ***"делать"***. Поэтому слова в историческом смысле можно считать однокоренными. Беда только, что в школе этот факт лучше не вспоминать.

Вот что у Фасмера.

> **деть** 
>   Происходит от праслав. *dedi̯ǫ, от кот. в числе прочего
>   произошли: ст.-слав. дѣти, дѣѭ (стар. деждѫ), ст.-слав., др.-русск.
>   дѣꙗти, дѣлати, русск. деть, дену; деять, укр. дíти, дíну, болг. дя́на
>   «кладу», сербохорв. дjе̏не̑м, дjе̏ти, словенск. dė́nem, dė́ti, чешск.
>   ději, dít «деть», словацк. diať, польск. dzieję, dziać «делать,
>   девать», в.-луж. dźeć «прясть, ткать», н.-луж. źaś — то же. Ст.-слав.
>   деждѫ — 1 л. ед., др.-русск. дежеть — 3 л. ед.; праслав. *dedi̯ǫ
>   сохранило в наст. врем. стар. редуплицированную основу. Слав. dějǫ,
>   děnǫ — новообразования. Праслав.*dedi̯ǫ восходит к праиндоевр.
>   *dheh₁-, ср. лит. dedù; стар. demì «кладу», dė́ti, латышск. dēt, др.-инд. dádhāti «кладет», авест. dađāiti — то же, греч. τίθημι, буд.
>   θήσω «кладу, ставлю», лат. faciō, fēcī «делаю» (греч. ἔθηκα); другая
>   ступень чередования: др.-в.-нем. tuon, др.-сакс. do^n «делать» (ср.
>   нем. tun, англ. do, deed). Сюда же ст.-слав. благодѣть δῶρον, χάρις,
>   лит. dė́tis «ноша», готск. gadēþs «дело», др.-в.-нем. ta^t «дело»; ср.
>   также одёжа, оде́жда, де́ло.

Про "надежду" он тут не говорит, но это есть в отдельной статье.

> Происходит от надежда, далее от праслав. *na-dedi̯a, от кот. в числе
>   прочего произошли: др.-русск. надежа, ст.-слав. надежда (др.-греч.
>   ἐλπίς); прост. русск. надёжа, белор. надзёжа, болг. наде́жда, устар.
>   польск. nadziewać «надевать на себя». Из *na-dedi̯a от на- и děti
>   (деть).